# Slack Upload : Error while trying to upload using Curl

Tags: curl, slack, slack-api

I am trying to upload a local file using curl command which I got to know about from [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload)
but while trying to run the command, It is not working and throwing error:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"not_authed"}
```

Command I am running is:

```
curl -F file=testsend.txt -F channels=#channel -F token='token' -F filetype=post https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message you got, the access token you are using does not seam to be valid. Please double-check that you are using a valid access token, should look something like this:

```
-F token='xoxo-123456789-123456789'
```

I am assuming you did not use `'token'` as access token. That would obviously not work.

to get an access token you want to create a Slack app and install it to your workplace (see [documentation](https://api.slack.com/internal-integrations) here), or you can get a [legacy token](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) for test purposes.

Also make sure your access token has the needed permissions for uploading files, e.g. `files:write:user`

Comment: Thanks Erik for the reply. I was passing Jenksin-CLI token for particular channel, whereas the command worked when I used my user token something like 'xoxp....'. Is there any where if I can upload files using Jenkins-CLI channel token and not my user token?

Comment: Depends, Do not really know what you mean by "Jenkins-CLI channel" token. The above error message implies that its invalid and it can not be used. So guess you will need to use your own token. Or you create a Slack app with the correct permissions to get a more neutral access token.

Answer (score 0):

For others where the accepted solution doesn't work.
Adding the token to the headers worked for me.

It shouldn't matter if the token is a parameter or header but it definitely did for me.

e.g.

```
curl -F file=@cycling.jpeg -F "initial_comment=Hello, Leadville" -F channels=C0R7MFNJD -H "Authorization: Bearer xoxp-123456789" https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```