# how do i send html file to slack using curl command

Tags: curl, protractor, slack

I have file in directory as

```
cgi-bin   test.html   var
```

And i want to send test.html file to slack

my workspace is

```
https://hooks.slack.com/services/TJJFXMD0E/BNKRQTZAPDEEDXSEED
```

and i tried using curl cmd

```
 curl -X POST file=@/test.html https://hooks.slack.com/services/TJJFXMD0E/BNKRQTZAPDEEDXSEED
```

but it doesnot work

Comment: You can not upload files to an incoming webhook. Those are for messages only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slack Upload : Error while trying to upload using Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770153/slack-upload-error-while-trying-to-upload-using-curl)

Comment: I slack a notification message where I include a link to HTML report. Lmk if this may be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -F file=@example.txt -F "initial_comment=Example file" -F channels=<CHANNEL_ID>, <ANOTHER_CHANNEL_ID_IF_NEEDED> -H "Authorization: Bearer <BOT_USER_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN>" https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

read here for more details and see if it's help you:
https://dev.to/hakobyansen/upload-and-publish-a-file-on-slack-channel-with-bash-i2e